# How to save HashMap in XML file and getting it back in android?

Tags: android, xml, file, hashmap

I have a HashMap that contains some data in key value format (String,Object). I want to save that hashmap in XML format file in android phone memory and retrieve it again as it was in Map. How to achieve this in android.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this solve your problem, but did you check using sharedPreferences ?
it lets you save key-values, without you having to take care of creating a file and retrieving from it.
Its easy to create, insert and read

check it here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

```
//create - open the sharedPreferences file
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//get an editor
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();

//add key-value
prefsEditor.putString("MY_KEY", "MY_VALUE");
//commit 
prefsEditor.commit();

//get the value from key (the second param is the default if the value is null )
pref.getString("MY_KEY","VALUE_IF_NULL");
```

Comment: I am be really thankful to you for this answer. But if you give me some sample code of it then it would be more helpful for me. Can u?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainClass {
      public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {

        List list = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" });
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("list.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(list);
        oos.close();

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("list.ser");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        List anotherList = (List) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();


      }
    }
```